# SQL Relationships, foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask if there is a way to see the relationships, foreign keys in a specific table using SQL query. So far I have tried different stuff on the internet but with no success.

I have tried

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

which seems like the shortest way, but it's not working. I'm using myPhpAdmin.

Comment: You should tag your dbms because it's very specific, and I'm also sure you should find this information in the related docs

Comment: It's perfectly possible, and in fact most good ORMs do it. I have done it in around 10 different databases. What's your spefici database?

Comment: @The Impaler im using sql databse

Comment: please edit this question and add the names of tables and columns you are trying to join.

Comment: @DanishArain i found a solution and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @cUser "SQL" is just a language to write queries, but it's not the database. We need to know the specific database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for MariaDB server

```
select fks.table_name as foreign_table,
       '->' as rel,
       fks.referenced_table_name
              as primary_table,
       fks.constraint_name,
       group_concat(kcu.column_name
            order by position_in_unique_constraint separator ', ') 
             as fk_columns
from information_schema.referential_constraints fks
join information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     on fks.constraint_schema = kcu.table_schema
     and fks.table_name = kcu.table_name
     and fks.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    where fks.constraint_schema = 'HERE YOU WRITE THE NAME OF YOU DATA BASE'
group by fks.constraint_schema,
         fks.table_name,
         fks.unique_constraint_schema,
         fks.referenced_table_name,
         fks.constraint_name
order by fks.constraint_schema,
         fks.table_name;
```

the result is a table with all table names and their connections

Answer (score 0):

There query shows foreign key info:

```
select o2.name as ParentTableName, o.name as ReferencedTableName, fk.name as foreignKey_name, *
from sys.foreign_keys fk
inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
inner join sys.objects o2 on o.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
where o.name = 'table_name' or o2.name = 'table_name'
```

Comment: Can you explain what i have to replace in this query in order to work ( my table name) ect ?Thanks in advance !

Comment: @cUser Answer is updated. Check it! Please accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: It didn't work , it dosen't like the syntax after "from sys.foreign_keys fk", maybe it dosent work on maridDB server version.

Comment: @cUser As you did not mentioned the Platform, I thought it is SQL Server not MariaDB.

Comment: i said im using phpMyAdmin which is using MardiDB , i found a solution and posted it as an answer , thakns for help .